# event.target.id is not a function

Tags: javascript, events

my code seems to work. but when I click on a button, I get the error message event.target.id is not a function

this is my javascript code

```
var multiplyer = 1
var carparts = 0;
document.getElementById("karpartz").innerHTML = carparts;

function onButtonClick(event) {
if (event.target.id("car"))
 {carparts = carparts + multiplyer;
  document.getElementById("karpartz").innerHTML = carparts;}} 


const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', onButtonClick);
```

And this is my html:

```
<button id="car"type="submit">
  <img src="example" 
alt="buttonpng" border="0" />
</button>

<button id="clickpower">
  upgrade click power
</button>
<button id="">
  upgrade idle scrapping
</button>

<p id="karpartz"></p>

<html>

  <body>
    <h1>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write(karpartz)

      </script>
    </h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

what do i do?

Comment: You want to use `event.target.id === "car"` and probably don't want to use `document.write()`. Your code is missing closing `)` at the event listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently you have 2 issues.
1st, you are trying to use your event listener as it were a function (what it is not), therefore you are getting this error message.
to resolve it you must replace `event.target.id("car")` to `event.target.id === "car"`

2nd, you are trying to access 'karpartz' in your HTML and it is not defined in the scope of your HTML. you should use `document.getElementById("karpartz").innerHTML` instead `document.write(karpartz)`

Answer (score 0):

The way you're trying to access the value of the `id` is as if "id()" were a function. If you want to get the value of the id you can do the following.

```
if (event.target.id === "car") {
  // more code 
}
```